# How do I Connect from Host to Cassandra using Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm looking to setup a development testing environment and while I have things mostly setup I'm having difficulty connecting from the host machine (which is running Visual Studio) to the Cassandra cluster in docker (using **Docker Desktop for Windows**).  I'm guessing I'm just messing up the configuration settings and/or missing a setting; but cannot determine how to make this work (it does work for single node; just not multiple nodes, which is what I want to work with)

*What I have setup:*

> docker run --name tnode1 -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=tcluster -e CASSANDRA_DC=TDC1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=TRAC1 -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=10.0.75.2 -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch cassandra

I've also tried with the -p switch

> docker run --name tnode1 -d -p 9042:9042 -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=tcluster -e  CASSANDRA_DC=TDC1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=TRAC1 -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=10.0.75.2 -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch cassandra

This seems to work in terms of if I put data in this and then connect to 10.0.75.2 from Visual Studio, everything works as I'd expect it to.  The issue comes when I go to add another node.

I've tried a number of ways, but it seems like they all end up with the second note starting up and then exiting and never joining the cluster.  If I leave out the CASSANDRA_BORADCAST_ADDRESS when setting up tnode1 then the cluster works, but I cannot get to it from Visual Studio.

Second Node (General Information)

> docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' tnode1
>   returns 172.17.0.2
>   docker exe -it tnode1 nodetool status
>   has the address as 10.0.75.2

Second Node (Attempt 1)

> docker run --name tnode2 -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=tcluster -e CASSANDRA_DC=TDC1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=TRAC1 -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=172.17.0.2 ca
>   ssandra
>   result: running nodetool status doesn't show tnode2 ... running docker ps -a shows "Exited (3) 30 seconds ago" for status

Second Node (Attempt 2)

> docker run --name tnode2 -d -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=tcluster -e CASSANDRA_DC=TDC1 -e CASSANDRA_RACK=TRAC1 -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=10.0.75.2 ca
>   ssandra
>   result: running nodetool status doesn't show tnode2 ... running docker ps -a shows "Exited (3) 28 seconds ago" for status

It seems as if the seed value isn't connecting and the new node then stops as a result.  Again if I take out the broadcast address then the node creation works, but I cannot connect from the host machine; I've attempted to add listener address, and -p parameter on tnode1 creation, but similar results.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm happy to take out all the broadcast items if I know how to connect to the cluster; when I do that and attempt 10.0.75.2 or 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.2 they all fail with NoHostAvailableException and then I put in the broadcast that goes away and enables the connection.

Comment: This is not cassandra specific, but when creating clusters it's generally easier to run the nodes all on a [user defined network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks) so they can all communicate like they would on a physical network, with no Docker in between. Using a [docker compose v2+ definition](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for the cluster will set the network up for you by default.

Comment: @Matt thanks, that was what I initially had for all the clusters, but then I couldn't connect to it from the host machine (where the visual studio/code instance was) ... so I added the broadcast flag to get that connection work and with that I lost the ability to connect nodes ... so it seems close; just need to know where/how to point the nodes so they all see each other and I can connect to from outside

Answer (score 2):

The following [compose cluster definition](https://github.com/deployable/docker-cassandra) works for me, I can connect with cqlsh from the Docker host and run the [test cql](https://github.com/deployable/docker-cassandra/blob/master/test.cql).

The memory is adjusted down from the default 1.5G as every time I brought up a new node, the previous node would exit due to a lack of memory in the Docker VM.

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  cassandra-1:
    image: cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: tcluster
      CASSANDRA_DC: TDC1
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 600M
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: 100M
    ports:
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9160:9160'
    networks:
      cassclus:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.75.11

  cassandra-2:
    image: cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: tcluster
      CASSANDRA_DC: TDC1
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: 10.0.75.11
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 600M
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: 100M
    networks:
      cassclus:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.75.12

  cassandra-3:
    image: cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: tcluster
      CASSANDRA_DC: TDC1
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: 10.0.75.11
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 600M
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: 100M
    networks:
      cassclus:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.75.13

networks:
  cassclus:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.75.0/24
          gateway: 10.0.75.1
```